# Image upload problem in crud operation CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, mkdir

Hello everyone I need to upload image in uploads folder, In uploads folder it automatically create a username folder in that folder, I need to upload a image. For that I used mkdir to create a folder I'm getting folder name in username but in that folder image not uploading. Please help me to solve this I will share my code.

Controller:

```
    public function insert()
    {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'ID', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'UserName', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('level', 'Level', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('salary', 'Salary', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bonus', 'Bonus', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $data = array('responce' => 'error', 'message' => validation_errors());
            } else {
                $config['upload_path'] = "../assets/uploads/";
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']     = '1000';
                $config['file_name'] =$this->input->post('username');

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("img")) {
                    $data = array('responce' => "error", 'message' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                } else {
                    $ajax_data = array(
                        'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
                        'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                        'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),
                        'level'=>$this->input->post('level')
                    );
                    $ajax_data2 =array(
                        'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
                        'salary'=>$this->input->post('salary'),
                        'bonus'=>$this->input->post('bonus'),
                        'img'=>$this->input->post()
                    );
                    $ajax_data2['img'] = mkdir($this->upload->data('file_name'),0777,true);

                    if ($this->login_model->insert_entry($ajax_data,$ajax_data2)) {
                        $data = array('responce' => "success", 'message' => "Data added successfully");
                    } else {
                        $data = array('responce' => "error", 'message' => "Failed to add data");
                    }
                }
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
        } else {
            echo "No direct script access allowed";
        }
    }
```

ajax file :

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var id = $("#id").val();
var username = $("#username").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var level = $("#level").val();
var salary = $("#salary").val();
var bonus = $("#bonus").val();
var img = $("#img")[0].files[0];

if (id == "" || username == "" || email == "" || password == "" ||level == ""||salary == ""||bonus == ""||img == "") {
  alert("All field are required");
} else {
  var fd = new FormData();

  fd.append("id", id);
  fd.append("username", username);
  fd.append("email", email);
  fd.append("password", password);
  fd.append("level", level);
  fd.append("salary", salary);
  fd.append("bonus", bonus);
  fd.append("img", img);
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Admin/insert",
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
          if (response.responce == "success") {
            Swal.fire({
                  position: 'center',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Your work has been saved',
                  showConfirmButton: false,
                  timer: 1500
                })
              $("#frm")[0].reset();
          } else {
              toastr['error'](response.message);
          }
      },
  });
}
});
```

Please check my code and help me to solve this problem. Thank you all

Comment: The `$config` you provided to the uploader specified the `upload_path` to be "../assets/uploads/", not a folder after the username. Could that be the problem?

Comment: yes after uploads folder , while I'm inserting new employee details with his profile pic it automatically create a folder with employee name in that folder employee image need to upload.

Comment: can you show the ajax?

Comment: please check the question I added ajax file now :).